# Como conectarse con SSH2 y llaves públicas con permisos "sudo"

Tags: linux, symfony3, seguridad

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de seguridad informática para GNU/LINUX en Symfony 3.4. pero al conectarme a las PC puedo ejecutar cualquier comando, menos los que requieren permisos de root obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
Error: LW_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED [code 0x00009cde] Incorrect access attempt
```

y la conexión es con contraseña en plano:

```
@ssh2_auth_password($connection, "$username", "mi-password")
```

Necesito conectarme seguramente con llaves publicas y privadas generadas con shh-keygen pero al intentarlo, nunca se conecta ni siquiera por la consola de la PC.
Y al ejecutar comandos sudo su o sudo  recibo un error porque no se puede insertar el password que pide desde la web.
En resumen lo que necesito es conectarme con llaves y que a ese usuario con llaves se le garantice el acceso root o sudo sin solicitar contraseña. He oído algo sobre PAM pero no es fácil de entender. Necesito ayuda.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: que sistema operativo utilizas y para hacer la coneccion? y validastes que en el archivo sshd tenga permitido el acceso ssh como root?

Comment: Utilizo el sistema operativo linux mint 19 y ya configure el sshd_config y el ssh_config para la conexion pero no se configurar el acceso root.

Comment: debes reiniciar los servicios

Answer (score 1):

Creo que quieres modificar el archivo /etc/sudoers con visudo, como así:

```
aaronkilik ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

(donde "aaronkliilk" es el usario)

Comment: Ya puedo ejecutar los comandos con permisos de sudo pero aún no me puedo conectar con los módulos PAM. La PC se conecta a otra con las llaves y PAM y no pide contraseña. Pero la aplicación web me dice que ha ocurrido un error de autenticación con las llaves. El código es correcto pero parece que no accede a las llaves.